# Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS Query Widget spatial filter relational layer

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am working on a project that has to spatially analyze a point set to a parcel layer in ArcGIS online. Inside the Query Widget, I am using the spatial filter *"Only return features that have a spatial relationship with features in another layer"*. I want to only allow for only 1 layer to be the relational layer, not every layer in the web map.

[image: Snapshot of spatial filter options]

[image: Drop down menu for query widget]

This is to minimize confusion for the end user and to generate results with limited interaction from them.

Is this possible without editing the code?